# Rounding values based on custom setting

Tags: vba, rounding

Good Afternoon all,

I have the following code that works well, however I need to expand it a little. What I need, is to round up if the decimal is >= #.8. If the value is <=#.7, then round down.

So, an example is 1.7 would = 1 ; 1.8 would = 2 ; -1.7 would = -1 and -1.8 would equal -2.

Is there something I can write that would build off what I have already created?

```
If (Worksheets("DATA_STAGING").Range("X27").Value) > 1 Or (Worksheets("DATA_STAGING").Range("X27").Value) < -1 Then
       Worksheets("STAFFING_VISUAL").Shapes("SinglesPackBUBBLE").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
       If Range("'DATA_STAGING'!X27").Value >= 0.7 Or Range("'DATA_STAGING'!X27").Value <= -0.7 Then
            Worksheets("STAFFING_VISUAL").Shapes("SinglesPackBUBBLE").TextFrame.Characters.Text _
            = Round((Worksheets("DATA_STAGING").Range("X27").Value), 0)
        Else
            Worksheets("STAFFING_VISUAL").Shapes("SinglesPackBUBBLE").TextFrame.Characters.Text _
               = 0
        End If
End If
```

Comment: Cannot test, but possibly something like `=if(Mod(A1,1)<0.8,rounddown(A1),roundup(A1))`?

Comment: So, I can get a formula to work however I cannot get this to work in VBA.

Comment: I need to keep the actual value in the cell, but have the rounding done behind the scenes and displayed on another sheet. THis also has to work with Negative #s. The formula I have is : =Round(x + if(x<0,ABS(-.2999),-.2999),0).

I need to somehow get that formula written into my vba code

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the code below yields the following "rounded" results:

```
 1.8  -->  2
 1.83 -->  2
 1.85 -->  2
 1.7  -->  1
-1.7  --> -1
-1.75 --> -2
-1.8  --> -2
```

Here's an example:

```
Sub TestRounding()
Dim numbers() As Variant
Dim num As Variant
numbers = Array(1.8, 1.83, 1.85, 1.7, -1.7, -1.75, -1.8)

For Each num In numbers
    Select Case GetMod(CDbl(num))
        Case Is >= 0.8
            Debug.Print num & " --> " & Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(num, 0)
        Case Is <= 0.7
            Debug.Print num & " --> " & Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(num, 0)
        Case Else
            'there should not be anything here because we round num in the GetMod function
    End Select
Next


End Sub
Function GetMod(num As Double) As Double
    num = Round(num, 1) 'to account for anything like 1.74, etc.
    GetMod = Abs(num) - Int(Abs(num))
End Function
```